# Go to page based on input entry jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this form to redirect me to a page based on what is in the input fields. The problem is that i see the console.log but the page simply refreshes instead of taking me to the page i want to go

input has `id="inputLink"`

submit has `onsubmit="submitPage()"`

The function

```
var inputVal = $('#inputLink');

function submitPage(){
    $(inputVal).on('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if($(inputVal).val() == 'home'){

                window.location.href = 'index.php';
                console.log('1');

            }else if($(inputVal).val() == 'services'){

                window.location.href = 'services.php';
                console.log('2');

            }else if($(inputVal).val() == 'portfolio'){

                window.location.href = 'portfolio.php';
                console.log('3');

            }else if($(inputVal).val() == 'about'){

                window.location.href = 'about.php';
                console.log('4');

            }else if($(inputVal).val() == 'contact'){

                window.location.href ='contact.php' ;
                console.log('5');

            }else{
                alert('undefined');
                console.log('6');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add `event.preventDefault()` at the top

Comment: Also, is that keypress event handler ***inside*** the callback for form submit? That's not going to work

Comment: @adeneo thanks. That was the problem actualy. Project was done and worked even better than i predicted. Problem was the handler inside the function

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onsubmit` to `onsubmit="submitPage(); return false;"`.  Also your logic can be greatly simplified by changing the `home` value to `index` and implementing the following.

```
    $('#inputLink').on('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           var where = $('#inputLink').val();
           window.location.href = where + '.php'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adjusting your jquery to be prepared once the page has loaded -- you don't need to have it in it's own function since jquery is capable of listening for events on its own. I would also remove the `onsubmit` event attribute since a "submission" implies that you are submitting form data, but in this case, your input and accompanying button is acting as a dynamic link. You can also clean up the jquery a little by better utilizing your `inputVal` variable.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var inputVal = $('#inputVal').val();
        $('#goLink').on('click', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                if(inputVal == 'home') {
                    window.location.href = 'index.php';
                    console.log('1');
                } else if(inputVal == 'services') {
                    window.location.href = 'services.php';
                    console.log('2');
                } else if(inputVal == 'portfolio') {
                    window.location.href = 'portfolio.php';
                    console.log('3');
                } else if(inputVal == 'about') {
                    window.location.href = 'about.php';
                    console.log('4');
                } else if(inputVal == 'contact') {
                    window.location.href ='contact.php' ;
                    console.log('5');
                } else {
                    alert('undefined');
                    console.log('6');
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

And then you could use this HTML without a form:

```
<input id="inputLink" type="text"></input>
<input id="goLink" type="button">Go!</input>
```